# C# unity Trigger 2d

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Soy nuevo en esto de unity y programación c# en general, necesito ayuda.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cuando estés solo dentro de un collider al presionar la tecla espacio ocurra algo?

Intente algo así pero hasta ahora no lo consigo:

---

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if ("no se que poner para cuando presiones una tecla se active")
        {
            animator.SetBool("idle", false);
            
            Destroy(destroy);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener información sobre los controles debes usar [`Input`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html).

Con `Input.GetKey()` puedes saber si la tecla está siendo presionada.

`Input.GetKeyDown()` y `Input.GetKeyUp()` devuelven `true` en el primer frame que la tecla es presionada y soltada respectivamente.

Para que quede más claro, si usas un código como este:

```
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
        Debug.Log("Down");
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
        Debug.Log("Pressed");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)){
        Debug.Log("Up");
    }
}
```

Si presionas la barra espaciadora la consola mostrará una salida parecida a esta:

```
Down
Pressed
Pressed
...
Pressed
Up
```

---

También puedes usar el nuevo [Input System](https://unity.com/es/features/input-system) pero es más complejo de usar.

Mejor familiarizate con el viejo y cuando lleves un buen tiempo programando te será fácil hacer la transición.